# Debugging deadlock on Android in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, deadlock

I have to develop new features and change some extisting ones in a buggy extensive Android application (where any changes may affect completely "unrelated" part of code) and I encountered a bug where application freezes (not responding).

So I figured it is probably a deadlock. But how to debug this? I cannot go step by step since we have many threads running and I dont know where to put a breakpoint...

Is there any way to break in debug and get a line (or part of code) where application is currently running?

Hope its not too chaotic, but I am exhausted from hours of testing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse.

1. You can suspend the debug session from the debug view.
2. Check the threads currently in action
3. From the stack trace of threads you can get a fair enough view of the current situation.

For further investigation you can use JConsole to debug the deadlock.

Check here https://kellicker.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/deadlock-debugging-in-eclipse/

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: So if you suspend your debug session in the debug view...you get to see all the threads running for your application...clicking on each thread will reveal the stack trace of it

Comment: Confirmed - I found my deadlock. But when I suspended two threads that were causing deadlock at the time I was confused, because both threads were executing the same synchronized method (first line after declaration) - I would expect one at the beginning and one waiting at the beginning of another synchronized method (to create a loop). Do you know, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

As your app is multi-threaded, the best option may be to make use of debug logs in your code. You may get some clue about the part that is causing deadlock.

Comment: Yes, well, that is pretty much what I do now... putting logs everywhere. Now very nice, but what can I do :)